# Producing the nth largest number from a vector in R

Tags: r

I need to have a user enter a number from 0 to 1 (nth number). Returning the nth largest number within say a vector. So when n=1 it acts as the maximum of the vector outputting the largest number. I am new to coding in r. Any help on improving my code would be grateful let alone getting it to work.

```
KFUN <- function() {
bob <- c(1,2,3,6)
ANSWER <- readline("Enter k value:")
k <- ANSWER
if(k <= 1 && k >= 0) {
  if(0 < k <= .25) {
   bob[c(4)]
  }
  if(.25 < k && k <= .5) {
   bob[c(3)]
  }
  if(.5 < k && k <= .75) {
   bob[c(2)]
  }
  if(.75 < k && k <=1) {
   bob[c(1)]
  }
}
else {
stop("That is not within 0 to 1!")
  }
}
KFUN()
```

Best

Comment: Try `quantile(bob, k, type = 1)`.

Comment: It's rather unclear what is desired. "n-th largest" has very little to do with quantile unless the probability is set with the length in mind.

Comment: @BondedDust - I think the question is in regard to "How do I use `readline` to get numbers. " But who knows, this user never responds to anything.

Comment: OK, then downvote for lack of clarity.

Comment: @BondedDust - I vote to close.

Comment: I have a vector x = (1,2,3,4) and I want to output the largest number I would say max(c(x)). Now instead of using max() the goal is to use 0 to 1 which the user inputs an any number from 0 to 1(1 being the maximum number [4] and 0 being the min. number [1]). The challenge is when the user inputs .75 I need to output the number that is “75th” largest number out of the vector which would be [3]. I hope this is clearer. Sorry for the confusion and late responding.   Again, I am new to coding and this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'order' function:

```
nth_largest= function(vect, n){
    vect[rev(order(vect))][n]
}

bob <- c(3,6,1,2)    

nth_largest(bob, 1)
[1] 6
nth_largest(bob, 2)
[1] 3
nth_largest(bob, 3)
[1] 2
nth_largest(bob, 4)
[1] 1
```